# Julia: Poles and Roots of Log(z)

Tags: julia, julia-plots

Testing the Julia's package [RootsAndPoles.jl v2.0.0](https://github.com/fgasdia/RootsAndPoles.jl)  for the (complex) logarithm `f(z)=log(z)` with standard (default) parameters as described on GitHub by Piotr Kowalczyk I obtain the following result in a moderate domain around the origin

> number of roots: 1
> number of poles: 1

[image]

While the result for the root `z=1` is clear I do not understand the meaning/outcome of the pole at `z=-1`. Even for a non-standard branch cut, the Log 'function' has no pole at `z=-1` in contrast to the findings in the figure.

Is there a bug in the `Julia package` or do I overlook anything?

Comment: you're better off asking the question in that github repository than here...

Comment: It looks like the algorithm as implemented calculates the complex quadrant by [comparing the real and imaginary parts to zero](https://github.com/fgasdia/RootsAndPoles.jl/blob/b3d3bd8715eeddaca78fb7a8e21bd98df3dd9b2e/src/RootsAndPoles.jl#L144) rather than computing the argument of the complex number (see equation (1) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06522.pdf). That means it will incorrectly find quadrant changes at branch cuts. I can't be sure, but it's likely a bug, and you should probably notify the authors.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer - I have created an issue on GitHub.