# Julia: Are there any alternative packages to RootsAndPoles.jl available?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I am looking for a `Julia` package that finds the poles and roots within a given domain of a given arbitrary complex function. Unfortunately, the on `GitHub` available package `RootsAndPoles.jl` v(2.0.0) by Piotr Kowalczyk seems to have a bug [see my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75598483/10063208)
which would fit all my needs otherwise.

Is there a similar package available?